# Accessing URL-based API

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have developed a web application in PHP to list all  the movies I have in my hard disk. I found a website http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/ which gives the IMDB API. Now I need to make a request to this URL with some parameters. But I am not able to succeed in getting a response because of this cross-site request.

Is there any way to make use of this API?

I am running my application in localhost. I tested in both Firefox and Chrome and get an  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps proxy the request to a local server side php script using a socket and then relaying the data back into your JavaScript?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more. I am very new to this. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: I assumed you are making the request from your JavaScript.  I suggested perhaps instead passing the parameters to a php script on your box that uses a socket (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) that relays the response from the remote hosts api back in your JavaScript.  Request -> local php script -> remote host -> local php script -> Requester

Answer (score 0):

The API you want to use, supports JSON as a response type. This means you can easily fetch data from this API in Javascript. Underneath is a sample code (uses jQuery) that should work for you -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function imdbapi(data){
                  var items = [];
                  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    items.push('<li>' + key + "=>" + val + '</li>');
                  });

                  $('<ul/>', {
                    'class': 'my-new-list',
                    html: items.join('')
                  }).appendTo('body');
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/?q=Star+Trek&type=jsonp',
                  dataType: 'jsonp'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that, browsers restrict cross domain access to http requests. Did you try your script from localhost to fetch data from deanclatworthy.com? If not try it and post the response you get.

Comment: Seems you did not try the script. Yes, it does work from your browser. You missed the "dataType:jsonp" in $.ajax which forces a cross browser JSON request. Give the code snippet above a go.